# how to recuperate variable definie in if php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem at the insertion level, in fact, I've defined a variable ($ chrono) in if and I want to use it outside if to insert it into the database.
when I execute the code it shows me this error:

> Warning: PDOStatement :: execute (): in C:\wamp\www\Jeu\jouerJeu.php on line 109

```
<?php

 if(isset($_GET['chrono']) ){
         $chrono = $_GET['chrono'];
  }

if($_POST){
 // INSERTION DES INFOS DANS LA BDD :
 if(isset($_POST['rep'] ) ){
    $var= $_POST['rep'];
    $pos = strpos($var, '+', 1); 
    $id_quest=substr($var, $pos, strlen($var));
    $rep= substr($var, 0, $pos); 

    $resultat = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO 
     rep_loaba(id_quest,id_joueur,rep,id_loaba,score) VALUES 
     (:id_quest,:id_joueur,:rep, :id_loaba,:score)");

//INT
$resultat  -> bindParam(':id_quest', $id_quest, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resultat  -> bindParam(':id_joueur', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resultat  -> bindParam(':rep', $rep, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultat  -> bindParam(':id_loaba', $id_loaba, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resultat  -> bindParam(':score', $chrono, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if($resultat -> execute()){ 
    $id_insere = $pdo -> lastInsertId();
    $page=$_GET['page'];
    $next=$page+1;
    header('location:jouerJeu.php?page='.$next.'&id='.$id_loaba);

}
else{
    $msg .= '<div class="erreur">Erreur dans la requête !! </div>';
}

}else{
    header('location:jouerJeu.php?page='.$next.'&id='.$id_loaba);
}

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Tip: Try not to space out the arrow operator. `$pdo->lastInsertId()` instead of `$pdo  -> lastInsertId()`.

Comment: Where is `$chrono` coming from?

Comment: Just to be sure, you do mean to be passing chrono in the URL? Just asking because you're getting the other parameters from $_POST

Comment: I get the variable $ chrono from ajax code. var element = document.getElementById('arret');

    element.onclick = function() {
       var chrono=mySpan.innerHTML;
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {chrono : chrono},
        success: function(data)
        {
         console.log(chrono);
        }
       });    
    };

Answer (score 0):

If `$_GET['chrono']` isn't set, you never assign a value to `$chrono`, then you try to insert this undefined value into the database. You need to give it a default value so the later code will work properly.

```
if(isset($_GET['chrono']) ){
    $chrono = $_GET['chrono'];
} else {
    $chrono = 0; // or whatever is appropriate to insert into the DB.
}
```

Comment: but it does not take the value of $chrono it takes that 0.

Comment: There is no value of `$chrono` if the `GET` parameter isn't provided.